# Brand new domain and server using URL Rewrite flagged by Google for Phishing

Tags: apache, phishing, iis, url

I set up a VM with 1and1.com and registered a domain.  I'm running an app ([Jira](https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira)) that runs on its own Tomcat instance but I have set up URL Rewriting based on [this article](http://danny.bag.gs/blog/2010/05/14/iis7-tomcat-application-request-routing/) so that IIS can handle the requests from subdomains.

I navigated to the new subdomain and it loaded properly (much to my joy) but when I clicked the very first link to navigate around the site I got the Chrome phishing "red screen of near-death".

Is this simply due to the URL rewrite?  If so, is there a way around it?  If not, how else could this have happened?  The server is literally less than 24 hours old and the subdomain wasn't even an hour old.

**Update**
So I used the "Hey I'm not phishing" form that Google provides and 20 minutes later I don't get the warning on my site anymore.  I'm still curious how this happened so quickly and if I do something to avoid it.  My confidence in my configuration is shaken.

Comment: you might get access to people with more experience with this type of problem over at webmasters.SE?

Comment: hmm, seemed like you could "move" a question to a sister site but I don't see the option.  Must be a privilege you unlock?

Comment: you can flag it for the moderators and tell them to migrate - there is only a short list of pre-approved sister sites users can vote to migrate to

Answer (score 1):

The phishing warning you are getting is populated by Google. Not only does Google embed this warning in the Chrome browser but it is also embedded into the search results for Google Search.

This is done by Google based on automatic assessments which can sometimes be wrong. If you feel that your site has been incorrectly classified as a phishing site you can use [this form](https://www.google.com/safebrowsing/report_error/) to report an incorrect phishing warning. This normally takes about a day to process according to Google. If Google finds that the site is clean warnings from safe browsing and search results should be removed within 72 hours. If Google deems that the problem has not been fixed then the security issues report on Google Webmaster Tools will usually display more sample infected URL's to assist in you investigating the reason why this has happened and support you in rectifying it. This usually happens after a site has been hacked or if you have registered a domain that has been used for phishing in the past.

https://developers.google.com/webmasters/hacked/docs/request_review